# Changing SPField cause no changes

Tags: spfield, splist, content-type-hub

I try to change an SPField after SPList creation, but I'm not getting any results of that change. using this code:

```
    SPField oSPField = oSPList.Fields[new Guid("MyFieldGuid")];
    oSPField.ReadOnlyField = true;
    oSPField.ShowInEditForm = false;
    oSPField.ShowInNewForm = false;
    oSPField.Update();
```

and then...nothing happens. What's wrong?is there any change to change it without coding?

(the field CT is provided by an ContentType Hub.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are effectively changing the list schema, you may have to do an `oSPList.Update()` as well.

Comment: even with that update, still not working...

Comment: Does your site have Output Caching enabled?

Comment: no, it's unchecked...